# Best way to override the table-hover color using Bootstrap 4 tables and SCSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

We have a simple Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6) table with the hover option enabled.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample 1</td>
        <td>Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample 2</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here is the documentation to the Bootstrap 4 table options](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/). Bootstrap 4 appears to use hover states within SCSS.

What is the best way to override the row hover color using SCSS?

Comment: How are you using bootstrap - are you pulling from an external CDN or did you download the SCSS files to your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the only way to achieve that, and it would be same for both css and scss

```
.table-hover> tbody> tr:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace "teal" with whatever color you want, or set it to the same color as the background color if you don't want the hover effect.

Here's a link. https://codepen.io/MikeIke/pen/PjJoGN

```
tr:hover{
    background-color:teal !important;
}
```